# Calculate formula through unique rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say that I have these tables/associations :

```
Product has_many :keywords, :through => :product_keywords 
Keyword has_many :products, :through => :product_keywords
```

And the ProductKeyword table is :

```
=> ProductKeyword(id: integer, keyword_position: integer, product_id: integer, keyword_id: integer)
```

Let's picture the prk variable as a list of products. Each product can have many keywords and keyword is defined as :

```
=> Keyword(id: integer, phrase: text)
```

Multiple keywords could contain the same phrases in terms of the text of the Keyword, but they are different database entries.

What I want to do is create a table with all the keywords of all the products and for each keyword calculate the sum of all those keywords that had a keyword_position < 10.

So if 5 products have the same keyword phrase(say "beach") and thus 5 different entries and their respective ProductKeyword keyword_positions are [1, 6, 11, 13, 3], I want that keyword to return a unique entry associated with the sum of less than 10 keyword_positions, which in this case would be 3.

I have tried a few different things, but end up confusing myself. What is the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the below code should produce the data you're looking for:

```ruby
Keyword
  .joins(:product_keywords)
  .where(ProductKeyword.arel_table[:keyword_position].lt(10))
  .group(Keyword.primary_key)
  .select(
    Keyword.arel_table[Arel.star],
    Arel.star.count.as('product_count')
  )
```

This will run the following SQL query (syntax may vary depending on your database):

```sql
SELECT "keywords".*, COUNT(*) AS product_count
FROM "keywords"
INNER JOIN "product_keywords" ON "product_keywords"."keyword_id" = "keywords"."id"
WHERE "product_keywords"."keyword_position" < 10
GROUP BY "keywords"."id"
```

That will return a list of `Keyword` records; you can run `.product_count` on each of these records to determine how many associated `ProductKeyword` records there are with a `keyword_position` value of less than 10.

You could then create a table to hold the data produced by the above code.

---

If you wanted to determine the count for a specific `Keyword` record without running that whole query, the following code should produce that count:

```ruby
my_keyword.product_keywords.where(ProductKeyword.arel_table[:keyword_position].lt(10)).count
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. I need to understand more about Arel, I will spend some time understanding this. It's a bit late here now, but I will try that first thing in the morning and let you know if that worked. Looks nice on first glance, thanks a lot for taking the time to help !

Comment: @Spyros Happy to help! Also something that might help as you're learning about Arel is that you can run `.to_sql` on many Arel snippets to see what SQL they're going to generate.

Comment: Maybe change the alias `count` to `product_count` to avoid confusion with known methods. Additionally we can change this `Arel::Nodes::Count.new([Arel.star]).as('count')` to `Arel.star.count.as('product_count')` which might be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @engineersmnky Those are good suggestions; thanks. I've updated the answer to reflect them.